# How to get a node level with Stanford dependency parser

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I would like to know if there is any method that allows to give the node level of the parse given by Stanford dependency parser. I haven't found the method that gives the node level. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stanford NLP pipeline contains the class [ExhaustiveDependencyParser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/ExhaustiveDependencyParser.html) as well as the interface [ViterbiParser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/ViterbiParser.html), both of which have methods from which you can get a `Tree` object. This, in turn, has a [`depth(Tree)`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html#depth%28edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree%29) method. Using this method with the root node as argument should suffice.